# Какой частью речи является знаменатель дроби?

Tags: числительные

По определению, дробные  числительные являются составными: первая часть — это целое количественное числительное, а вторая — порядковое числительное: две третьих, три четвертых. А почему в этом определении знаменатель дроби называют порядковым числительным, ведь здесь нет порядка счёта. А если это не порядковое числительное, то какая это часть речи? Или это неверное определение?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
Большое спасибо за ответы. Но мне вот то непонятно.

1) Если посмотреть в толковом словаре Ожегова, то там, например, слово «пятый» имеет два значения: 1) порядковое числительное, отнесенное к числу пять; 2)  относительное прилагательное со значением «получаемый делением на пять» - к примеру,  пятая часть.  Так, может быть, логичнее считать знаменатель дроби не порядковым числительным, а ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫМ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМ?

2)  А ДРОБНОЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ СТРОИТЬ ТАК: две пятых (части)  участка→ две (каких?) пятых  (части) участка→ две пятых участка. Здесь промежуточное слово «части/доли» ОПУЩЕНО, поэтому слово  «участка»  все время в Р.п. В действительности же именно пропущенное слово «части/доли» и управляет Р.п. существительного «участка».
Хотелось бы услышать ваш комментарий на эти рассуждения.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2. 
Существует  две классификации числительных: по семантическому и грамматическому принципу. Порядковое числительное – это грамматическое прилагательное, семантически имеющее отношение к теме счета. Но в дробях речь идет не только о грамматике, но и о семантике тоже. Сложно считать, что знаменатель дроби имеет значение порядка при счете - по-моему, это всё-таки относительное прилагательное, связанное с ДЕЛЕНИЕМ на определенное количество частей.

Comment: Согласна со всеми рассуждениями.Как бы ни назвали знаменатель,а склоняется он как прилагательное и сочетается с предполагаемым сущ. «части/доли», поэтому управляет Р.п. существительного во всех падежах дробного числительного или счётного прилагательного(как угодно).

Answer (score 1):

Почему неверное? Взгляды на числительное различны. http://podelise.ru/docs/33533/index-3161-2.html   В широком понимании числит. считаются слова, обозначающие кол-во предметов (один, два) и их порядок при счете (второй, третий). В узком – числит. считаются только количественные числит., а порядковые включаются в состав прилагательных. Щерба не приводит числ в списке частей речи. Виноградов  Имя числит. относил к ИМЕНАМ, придерживался узкого понимания.

Аргументы в пользу узкого понимания: 1) количественные числительные имеют признаки (отсутствие категории числа), которыми они отличаются от всех других имен 2) признаки порядковых числ сближают их с прилагательными (род, число, падеж, склонение)

В пользу широкого понимания: 1)порядковые числ образуются от количественных 2) способность числительных образовывать многосоставные комплексы 3) употребление количественных числ в функции порядковых (квартира 35)

Дробные числительные тоже выделяют далеко не все грамматики. Отрицание этого разряда чётко сформулировано в Русской грамматике–1980: «В некоторых классификациях к составным числительным причисляются так называемые дробные числительные типа две пятых (подразумеваются доли единицы), семь двадцатых, девять тридцать вторых; одна целая шесть десятых, три целых и двадцать пять сотых . Однако такие сочетания не могут быть отнесены к числительным. Они представляют собой имеющие количественное значение сочетания слов (часто с союзом и ), относящихся к разным частям речи. В отличие от сочетаний с количественными и собирательными числительными существительные при таком сочетании слов всегда имеет форму род. п. ед. ч. (слова pluralia tantum – род. п. мн. ч.): пять десятых участка, три пятых суток; пяти десятым участка, трем пятым суток » [Русская грамматика–1980, т. 1, с. 574].

В школе говорят:- Что представляет собой числитель дробного числительного? (Количественное числительное, которое изменяется как числительное, обозначающее целое число).
 - А знаменатель дробного числительного? (Порядковое числительное, которое изменяется как прилагательное во множественном числе).

Иногда в науке знаменатель называют субстантивированным числительным, иногда субстантивированным прилагательным. 2/6 -две(части)чего? шестых. Тоже логично.

Так что пока учёные не пришли к общему мнению,какая часть речи  знаменатель дроби.

Comment: >2/6 -две(части)чего? шестых.
Я *не в теме*, но скажу. 
Здесь не *части*, а *штуки*: а) (сколько?) две штуки, б) (чего или каких?) шестых долей. Термин *шестая (доля)* склонен рассматривать не как порядковое числительное, а как прилагательное, инициирующее имя и сущность (размер в сопоставлении с целым) доли.

Comment: >не как порядковое числительное, а как прилагательное  
  
Это вещи грамматически почти неразличимые. Можно спорить о том, существуют ли вообще эти самые "порядковые" - или это просто некая группа прилагательных, выделяемая по особым семантическим (но не грамматическим)свойствам. Но об этом надо спорить вообще, а не в рамках узкого вопроса о знаменателе дроби.

>(чего или каких?) шестых долей.  
  
Вот это единственный интересный момент, действительно имеющий отношение к вопросу об атрибуции знаменателя дроби. Порядковые числительные отвечают на вопрос "который", а знаменатель - "какой?"

Answer (score 0):

Все здесь правильно. Исторически знаменатель - порядковое числительное. И я думаю, ничего с тех пор принципиально не изменилось. *Я говорю о сути, а не о том, какая часть числительное вообще - этот вопрос в древнерусском изрядно запутан.*

Здесь **есть** порядок счета. 
Наши предки мыслили таким образом.
Пусть некое "Целое" (мешок монет) надо поделить поровну между десятью участниками похода. 
Доставалось по одной монете - и раскладывалось по одной в кучки - в первую, во вторую, в десятую.
Вот эта "десятая кучка" и была **одной "десятой" дОлей (целого)** каждого. Если кому-то полагалось больше, то ему шло, скажем, **три "десятых" доли (целого)**. 
Ну или там **семь "двадцать вторых" долей**. Так появились названия русских дробей.
Разумеется, очень скоро процедура упростилась, это осталось просто в понимании смысла раздела. Но еще в XIX веке так объясняли в школах простые дроби.

Нечто подобное мы и сейчас используем для того чтобы отделить, скажем, пятую часть стоящих в строю. "На первый-пятый рассчитайсь!" "**Пятые** номера, шаг вперед!"

Не вижу причин пересматривать это понимание знаменателя дроби. Сейчас вместо "доля" в быту чаще говорят "часть", но остальное - в полной силе.